# What's wrong with my JDBC mySQL statement? Apparently my WHERE clause is messed

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

What's wrong with my JDBC mySQL statement? Apparently my WHERE clause is messed up.  Note: the first value is defined in the actionListener and the = value is the variable in the database.

```
searchBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        list.clearSelection();

        //connect to database

        String afName= auth_fName.getText();
        String aMI =  auth_MI.getText();
        String alName = auth_lName.getText();

        String tField = titleField.getText();
        String sField = subjectField.getText();

        //PR.111.002 - “Core Java”,  Cay Horstmann  - AVAILABLE

        try
        {
            Connection conn = Database.getConnection();

            Statement s = conn.createStatement();

            if (!afName.equals("") && (!aMI.equals ("")) && (!alName.equals(""))&& (!tField.equals("")) && (!sField.equals("")))
            {
                selectString = "SELECT call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, availability"
                                + "FROM book, transaction"
                                + "WHERE aLName = 'auth_LName' AND afName = 'auth_FName' AND aMI = 'auth_MI'"
                                + " AND title = 'title' AND sField = 'subject'";
                result ="";

            }

            s = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery(selectString);
            while (rs.next())
                {
                    String call_Number = rs.getString("call_Number");
                    String title = rs.getString("title");
                    String auth_lName = rs.getString("auth_lName");
                    String auth_MI = rs.getString ("auth_MI");
                    String auth_fName = rs.getString("auth_fName");
                    String availability = rs.getString("availability");

                view = new View (call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_MI, auth_fName, availability);

                vList.add(view);
                }
        s.close();
        conn.close();

        list.setListData(vList.toArray());

        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot some whitespace.

Replace

```
selectString = "SELECT call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, availability"
    + "FROM book, transaction"
    + "WHERE aLName = 'auth_LName' AND afName = 'auth_FName' AND aMI = 'auth_MI'"
    + " AND title = 'title' AND sField = 'subject'";
```

by

```
selectString = "SELECT call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, availability"
    + " FROM book, transaction"
    + " WHERE aLName = 'auth_LName' AND afName = 'auth_FName' AND aMI = 'auth_MI'"
    + " AND title = 'title' AND sField = 'subject'";
```

For future SQL problems, you would help yourself a lot if you print/debug the SQL statement or the `PreparedStatement` before executing it. This kind of mistakes can then more easily be spotted.

```
logger.debug(selectString);
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you need to close DB resources, including `ResultSet` in the `finally` block of the `try` block where they are been acquired. This way you prevent resource leaking in case of exceptions.

Comment: Thank you!!!  That is one insidious error!  It works. . . almost now I have another error: It states that there is a constraint violation and that call_Number is ambigous?  I am googling it now, but do you know what it might be.  Should I change the call_Number string in my while statement to call_Num?  I dunno.  Anyway, thanks for your help BalusC!!!

Comment: You're welcome. As to the new problem, just press `Ask Question` on right top if you stucks :)

Answer (score 4):

```
    selectString = "SELECT call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, availability"
                + "FROM book, transaction"
                + "WHERE aLName = 'auth_LName' AND afName = 'auth_FName' AND aMI = 'auth_MI'"
                + " AND title = 'title' AND sField = 'subject'";
```

The problem is you dont have a space between **transaction** and **WHERE**...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I see it. It's not exactly the where clause, that's just what the parser is pointing to. It's *near* the where clause. Here is what your SQL is if you remove the line breaks:

```
SELECT call_Number, title, auth_lName, auth_fName, auth_MI, availabilityFROM book, transactionWHERE aLName = 'auth_LName' AND afName = 'auth_FName' AND aMI = 'auth_MI' AND title = 'title' AND sField = 'subject'
```

The problem is that you don't have spaces between "availability" and "FROM", or between "transaction" and "WHERE". If you add spaces to the end of your strings on each line, it should work.

This kind of mistake happens all the time. I got in the habit of adding an extra space to the end of any line of SQL query in my apps to prevent me from accidentally doing this when I change a query later.

Also, note that "transaction" is a reserved word. While you don't seem to be encountering problems, you may accidentally find one in the future where the parser is interpreting it as a keyword instead of a table/field name. Quoting it (with backticks in MySQL) will help with this, but if it's possible you may way to rename it. Those "I accidentally used a keyword as a name" bugs can be a real pain to track down.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will definitely revise the variable name transaction as well.